# Issues with request, and cheerio when web-scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I'm trying to write a code that makes a request to a website, for webscraping

So this are the steps:

**Here First part of Code STARTS**

1. The program makes the request to the **mainURL**
2. The program selects some objects from the html of the **mainURL**, and store them in an array of objects(advert), on of the properties of the object, is it's link, which we'll call **numberURL**, that the code automatically selects using a css selector, the amount of objects is something like 80-90;
3. The program makes requests to every **numberURL**(80-90 requests),
   and for each of them it does set another properties to the same object, and selects another link, that we'll call **accountURL**
4. The program creates an CSV file where it writes every object in different rows

**Here First part of Code ENDS**

So actually the first part works pretty good, it doesn't have any issues, but the second part does

**Here Second part of Code STARTS**

5. The program makes requests to every **accountURL** from the previous object
6. The program selects some objects from the html of the **accountURL**, and stores them in an another array of another objects(account), also using CSS selectors
7. The program should console.log() all the **account** objects

**Here Second part of Code ENDS**

But the second part does have some bugs, because when console.logging the objects we see that the objects properties doesn't changed their default value.

So in debugging purposes I took one advert object and putted it's value manually from the code

`post[0].link = 'https://999.md/ru/profile/denisserj'`

Finally when running the code for this object it actually works correctly, so it shows the changed properties, but for the rest of them it doesn't.

I tried to set some Timeouts, thinking that the code tries to read the link, before the second request finished, but no effects

I also tried to console.log the link, to see if it exists in the array, so it actually exists there, but also no effect.

Finally here is the code:

```
// CLASSES
class advert {
    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.tile = new String();
        this.link = new String();
        this.phone = new String();
        this.account = new String();
        this.accountLink = new String();
        this.text = new String();
        this.operator = new String();
    }
    show() {
        console.log(this.id, this.title, this.link, this.phone, this.account, this.accountLink, this.text, this.operator);
    }

}
class account {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 0;
        this.createdAt = 0;
        this.phone = [];
        this.ads = [];
        this.adsNumber = 0;
    }
    show() {
        console.log(this.name, this.createdAt, this.phone, this.ads, this.adsNumber);
    }
}

// HEADERS
const mainRequest = require('request');
const auxRequest = require('request');
const cheerio1 = require('cheerio');
const cheerio2 = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const fs2 = require('fs');
const adFile = fs.createWriteStream('anunturi.csv');
const accFile = fs2.createWriteStream('conturi.csv');

// SETTINGS
const host = 'https://999.md'
const category = 'https://999.md/ru/list/transport/cars'
const timeLimit = 60; //seconds

// VARIABLES
let post = [];
let postNumber = 0;
let acc = [];

// FUNCTIONS
function deleteFromArray(j) {
    post.splice(j, 1);
}

function number(i) {
    let category = post[i].link;
    auxRequest(category, (error, response, html) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            const $ = cheerio1.load(html);
            let phone;
            const siteTitle = $('strong').each((id, el) => {
                phone = $(el).text();
            });
            const txt = $('.adPage__content__description').html();
            const person = $('.adPage__header__stats').find('.adPage__header__stats__owner').text();
            const linkToPerson = host + $('.adPage__header__stats').find('.adPage__header__stats__owner').find('a').attr('href');
            post[i].phone = phone;
            post[i].account = person;
            post[i].accountLink = linkToPerson;
            post[i].text = txt;
            if (i == postNumber) {
                console.log('1. Number Putting done')
                writeToFileAd(accountPutter, writeToFileAccount);
            }
        }

    });
}

function writeToFileAd() {
    adFile.write('ID, Titlu, Link, Text, Cont, LinkCont, Operator\n')
    for (let i = 0; i <= postNumber; i++) {
        adFile.write(`${post[i].id}, ${post[i].title}, ${post[i].link}, ${post[i].phone}, ${post[i].account}, ${post[i].accountLink}, ${post[i].operator}\n`);
    }
    console.log('2. Write To File Ad done')
    accountPutter();
}

function accountAnalyzis(i) {
    let category = post[i].link;
    const mainRequest = require('request');
    category = category.replace('/ru/', '/ro/');
    mainRequest(category, (error, response, html) => {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            const $ = cheerio2.load(html);
            const name = $('.user-profile__sidebar-info__main-wrapper').find('.login-wrapper').text();
            let createdAt = $('.date-registration').text();
            createdAt = createdAt.replace('Pe site din ', '');
            const phones = $('.user-profile__info__data').find('dd').each((id, el) => {
                let phone = $(el).text();
                acc[i].phone.push(phone);
            });
            const ads = $('.profile-ads-list-photo-item-title').find('a').each((id, el) => {
                let ad = host + $(el).attr('href');
                acc[i].ads.push(ad);
                acc[i].adsNumber++;
            });
            acc[i].name = name;
            acc[i].createdAt = createdAt;
            console.log(name)
            if (i == postNumber) {
                console.log('3. Account Putting done')
                writeToFileAccount();
            }
        }
    });
}

function writeToFileAccount() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= postNumber; i++) {
        accFile.write(`${acc[i].name}, ${acc[i].createdAt}, ${acc[i].phone}, ${acc[i].ads}, ${acc[i].adsNumber}\n`);
    }
    console.log('4. Write to file Account done');
}

function numberPutter() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= postNumber; i++) {
        number(i);
    }
}

function accountPutter() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= postNumber; i++) {
        accountAnalyzis(i);
    }
}

// MAIN
mainRequest(category, (error, response, html) => {
    let links = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        post[i] = new advert();
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        acc[i] = new account();
    }
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio2.load(html);
        const siteTitle = $('.ads-list-photo-item-title').each((id, el) => {
            const ref = host + $(el).children().attr('href');
            const title = $(el).text();
            post[id].id = id + 1;
            post[id].title = title;
            post[id].link = ref;
            links[id] = ref;
            postNumber = id;
        });
        post[0].link = 'https://999.md/ru/profile/denisserj'
        numberPutter()
    }

});
```

Comment: You really need to work on your minimum working examples

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in line

```
const siteTitle = $('.ads-list-photo-item-title').each((id, el) => {
```

What you actually want is `.find('a').each...`

Comment: Yeah but id doesn't change the results

Comment: You should debug it (I can't). Also instead of creating  ```for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        post[i] = new advert();
    }``` - create and push it inside ```each``` function - so you will see how many actual links found.

Comment: Doesn't help, i tried to put them in a constructor, neither that helps

Comment: The  main problem is that for post[0], that link i wrote manually in the code, the code does his work, but for the rest of them it doesn't